# Stored data in Pl-SQL cursor is dynamic or static?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

When a cursor declared, is it a static data set or after it declared if a new data entered before start the loop will it picked up for the loop or not ?

Comment: I think If data is committed before we call `OPEN cursor_name;`, it will pick up that data too.

Comment: A cursor just allocate the space. it has no data set. It contains the dataset of the query you open it for.

Comment: So data is fetched at run time correct? which means if a new data included in the time frame of opening cursor and declare cursor it will fetched the new row

Comment: @Optimuskck. No, once the cursor is opened, it gets the resultset if the query in the space allocated to it. Its like a table of the cursor. If you make changes to table it will not affect the resultset in the cursor resultset,

Comment: Yes, data is fetched at run time. No, it will not include changes that were applied after the cursor was opened. It fetches rows as at the time the cursor was opened. In plain SQL terms (without the added complexity of explicit cursor handling), if your report runs for an hour, the results won't reflect any changes that were made during that hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring the cursor defines the cursor with a name and the associated SELECT statement. After declaring the cursor, you need to open the cursor to allocate memory for the cursor and makes it ready for fetching the rows returned by the SQL statement into it. For example:

1. Declaring a Cursor
   CURSOR c_customers IS 
   SELECT id, name, address FROM customers;
2. Opening a Cursor
   OPEN c_customers;
3. After opening you can access one row at a time by fetching the cursor:
   FETCH c_customers INTO c_id, c_name, c_addr;
4. After fetching the cursor, just close the cursor:
   Close c_customers;

So it will not be picked up by the loop.

Comment: Correct, you can see the cursor as "definition" of "what to execute" later on. The moment you open the cursor is the exact moment for which your data set is valid. You can keep reading from the cursor as long as you like. The data it returns will always be representing the situation of your starting time. When the data is modified in other sessions and you wait too long you could get a SNAPSHOT TO OLD error.. See it this way: on open it takes a snapshot of the current situation. This snapshot will be valid until you close the cursor. Data modifications in other sessions are invisible to you.

Comment: True, data modifications will be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides [Statement-Level Read Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT221), which guarantees that data returned by a single query is committed and consistent as at the start of the query.

There are some details to do with transaction isolation levels, flashback query and user-defined functions that perform queries, but in general once a query has started (in procedural terms, when a cursor is opened) its results will be true as at that time, regardless of any data changes (committed or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in mysql and in mysql it is fetching the data.

I have created a new table and written a procedure. This procedure inserts two records in that newly created empty table, open cursor and select `FOUND_ROWS()` in `record_cnt` variable.

`FOUND_ROWS()` gives count of rows fetched by cursor. In Oracle it is `cursor_name%ROWCOUNT`.

In Oracle, definitely there will be other syntactical differences but I think behavior would be same and values will be visible to cursor if they are inserted and committed before opening the cursor.

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab(id int);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cursor_test(OUT record_cnt INT)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM my_tab;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES(1),(2);
  COMMIT;
  OPEN cur1;
  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO record_cnt;
  CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL cursor_test(@rec);

select @rec;
+------+
| @rec |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

Comment: my scenario is when you entered a record to table after you open the cursor but before the select statement. either in same session or different sessions

Comment: In that case it will not be available.